# Left join unknown column

Tags: mysql

I am getting Unknown column 'assessment_assessment_type_lookup.assessment_type_fk' in 'on clause' with the query below. The tables and columns are correct.

```
SELECT * FROM assessment
LEFT JOIN assessment_type 
ON assessment_type.assessment_type_pk = assessment_assessment_type_lookup.assessment_type_fk
LEFT JOIN assessment as ass
ON ass.assessment_pk = assessment_assessment_type_lookup.assessment_fk
LEFT JOIN unit_outcome
ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
LEFT JOIN unit
ON unit.unit_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk
LEFT JOIN unit_outcome as uo
ON uo.unit_outcome_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
LEFT JOIN assessment as ass2
ON ass2.assessment_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk
AND unit.unit_pk = '$unit_pk' GROUP BY assessment.assessment_pk
```

Comment: You don't have a table named `assessment_assessment_type_lookup` in the query.

Comment: Or if there is, the query isn't joining with it, so it can't reference columns in it.

Comment: @Barmar you are absolutely right. I removed my comment, which was considering what I usually do wrong (a simple typo) when I get such errors.

Comment: @Tenderfoot, here is an example of how you can join two tables `t1` and `t2` in mysql: `SELECT  select_list FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON join_condition;` In your sql query, the join conditions use table names (such as `assessment_assessment_type_lookup`) other than `t1` and `t2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to **join assessment** and **assessment_type** via  table **assessment_assessment_type_lookup** which can not be done.

If you wish to join 2 tables, you must use both of them in their **ON** clause.